# How to write something like Apache bench is Scala (multi-threaded way to hit a web page)

Tags: java, scala

How could I write a scala script to do the following, given the inputs:

```
url
total requests
total connections (threads)
```

So it would `request` x web pages from a given `url`, using x number of `threads`.

And it should look at the response of the request to make sure it was ok (not a failed request).

I'm guessing this is easier in Scala than Java because I have heard writing multi-threaded applications in Scala is much easier.

So:

```
>scalac -url localhost:8080/ -requests 1000 -connections 10
```

Would make 1000 requests, but hitting it with 10 threads at the same time.

Comment: You misheard: writing *concurrent* applications in Scala is much easier. And the main reason for that is that you don't write _multi-threaded_ applications. Instead, you use other concurrency abstractions which happen to be implemented through threads, but you don't see the threads. This is relevant here, because you want to guarantee N simultaneous threads, and that's one of the first things that is taken away from your control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a scala app to do just this, though it was built around stress-testing an API I was developing.  It's very easy to do concurrent requests using actors.  The general idea is you want to create an actor that when given a message, performs a single request.  Then you create multiple instances of the actor and distribute requests to them with a load balancer.

Here is a very simple implementation to give you an idea (using [Akka](http://akka.io) actors):

```
case class MakeRequest(url: String)
class RequestActor extends Actor {

  //force the actor to run in it's own thread
  self.dispatcher = akka.dispatch.Dispatchers.newThreadBasedDispatcher(self)

  def receive = {
    case MakeRequest(url) => //perform the request
  }
}

val totalRequests = 1000
val url = "http://..."
val totalConections = 4

//create one actor per connection and wrap them in a load balancer
val actors = (0 to totalConnections).map{i => actorOf[RequestActor].start}
val requestBalancer = loadBalancerActor(new CyclicIterator(actors))

//start sending requests
for (i <- 0 to totalRequests) {
  requestBalancer ! MakeRequest(url)
}

//send a poison pill to stop the actors after they've finished all the requests
requestBalancer ! Broadcast(PoisonPill)

//wait for the actors to finish
while (actors.foldLeft(false){ (b, a) => b || !a.isShutdown}) {
  Thread.sleep(300)
}

//stop the load balancer
requestBalancer ! PoisonPill
```

As you can see, I am sending `MakeRequest` messages to the load balancer, which distributes them across the actors.  Every actor has a message queue, so a single actor will make one request at a time, but together the actors will make requests concurrently.

This example doesn't provide a way to tally responses and you run the risk of overflowing the actors' queues, but these are easy to fix.  I've used this general idea to perform extensive stress testing and benchmarking with great success.

Comment: so where would you get the request 200OK or fail? and store it where? a concurrent collection?

Comment: The way I handle it is I create a single "collector" actor that receives responses from request actors.  When I create the request actors, I give them a reference to the collector, so when they make the requests they can send the responses to it.  The collector is then free to count successes and failures as they come in and output results to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy, naive way in Scala 2.9+ that, as Daniel suggested, ignores threads:

```
val url: String
val totalRequests: Int
def makeRequest(url: String): Boolean

val requests = (1 to totalRequests).par.map(i => makeRequest(url))
val successes = requests.count(r => r)
val failures = requests.count(r => !r)
```